# Calling method defined in Base Interface

Tags: c#, interface

If I have the following Interface structure;

```
public interface IPaymentTypeBase
{
    void PayNow();
    double Amount { get; set; }
}

public interface IPaymentTypePayPal : IPaymentTypeBase
{
    string UserName { get; set; }
    string Password { get; set; }
}

public interface IPaymentMethod<T>
{
}
```

Then I have the following classes;

```
public class PaymentTypePayPal : IPaymentTypePayPal
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public void PayNow()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class PaymentMethod<T> : IPaymentMethod<T> where T : IPaymentTypeBase
{
}
```

Then in my web application I have this;

```
IPaymentMethod<IPaymentTypePayPal> payer = (IPaymentMethod<IPaymentTypePayPal>) new PaymentMethod<PaymentTypePayPal>();
```

I'd now like to call `payer.PayNow();` but I'm just getting lost in interfaces etc and can't seem to make this work.

I believe this is a simple thing but am just missing the point entierly.

Can anyone help?

**Edit**

The intention here is to have a set of interface such as PayPal, Voucher, CreditCard all of which do their own payment gateway type of stuff.

So I'd like to instantiate a class that takes the Payment Type as an interface and call that interfaces PayNow method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

payer is of type `IPaymentMethod<IPaymentTypePayPal>`.

But `IPaymentMethod<T>` is defined as

```
public interface IPaymentMethod<T>
{
}
```

Therefore, it has no methods and you can't call `PayNow()` on it.

The same is true for `PaymentMethod<T>`, so you can't call any method on an instance of `PaymentMethod<PaymentTypePaypal>` either.

Maybe you can explain a little more what your intention is.

Comment: yeah i get that but if i now have IPaymentTypeCreditCard etc, how would i call the PayNow method in either paypal or credit card?  what would my interface structure need to be modified to?

Comment: what about `IPaymentTypeBase payer = new PaymentTypePayPal();` I don't quite understand why you need those empty classes...

Comment: you're saying i'm making this far more complex than it needs to be right?

Comment: yeah, I guess that's what I am saying :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure of why you are using that PaymentMethod class... But why cant you modify the interface IPaymentMethod to something like :

```
public interface IPaymentMethod<T> : IPaymentTypeBase
```

so that U can call the patNow method??

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use classes rather than interfaces whenever inheritance is involved. Also, in this case you've got more indirection than you probably need. If you model Payment as an abstract base class (with PayNow() and Amount) and PayPalPayment as the subclass, just instantiate the proper subclass from a factory and you're set, with all the flexibility you'd have with your approach, yet easier to understand and maintain, I think. (not really knowing all of the other requirements of your application)

Comment: Yeah I'm coming around to your thinking.  The idea here was that when a new payment method was needed, you could code against an interface thus making the process for a new developer a little clearer

Comment: I totally disagree. It's always better and more friendly to code against interfaces. Plus interfaces allow you multiple inheritance.